# Unable to get hold of iframe again after navigating within the iframe

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my webdriver test I'm switching to an Iframe and performing a client side navigation, then I want to get hold of the iframe's new url to perform some assertions:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);

// Click a link and navigate within the iframe.

. . . 

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

// Try to find the new url of the iframe.
iframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0);
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
String appDetailPageUrl = iframe.getAttribute("src");
```

but it fails with

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you switched to the `iframe` the driver context changed to the `iframe`, so all previously located elements were lost and are now stale.

In addition, if the `src` attribute is part of the `<iframe>` element you can't locate it from inside the `iframe`, the driver scop starts from the `<html>` tag inside it.

Take the attribute before the switch

```
iframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).get(0);
String appDetailPageUrl = iframe.getAttribute("src");
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

Comment: Gotcha. I notice that the iframe's src url remains the same even after clicking a link inside the iframe and navigating to a different page within the iframe. Why does this happen? I want to test that the url parameters are preserved after the navigation and available to the application being iframed.

Comment: @HughDarling The `src` attribute is the initial `iframe` source, `iframe` is basically a wrapper for external html code inside your html. I don't know how your site is built and what exactly you are trying to check, but perhaps you can extract those parameters from the url or another place?